# How to respond to caller in kroma.runtime/on-message

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, clojure, clojurescript

I'm writing chrome extension with [kroma](https://github.com/suprematic/khroma).

I'm calling following function in my popup.cljs:

```
(defn my-caller-function [timer]
  (runtime/send-message {:foo :bar
                         :responseCallback do-something}))
```

I'm listening to messages in my background.cljs

```
(defn init []
  (go-loop
    []
    (when-let [message (<! (runtime/on-message))]
      (process-message (:message message))
      ; here I'm trying to respond to my popup with "foo"
      ; but do-something is not called
      (apply (:response-fn message) "foo")
      (recur))))
```

As far as I understand `do-something` should be called with "foo" as argument. But it isn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know kroma, but if process-message is asynchronous, you need to return true from the on-message listener.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for responding. `process-message` is not async in my case.

Comment: Dumb question: why should :response-fn return the :responseCallback property?

Comment: I think that's korma implementation of https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-sendMessage 3d parameter. @kennytilton

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].